# my app goes to a few loops before result and slow the process

Tags: java, android

I am working on bolding and unbolding the text but when I click the button it goes to a few loops and then show my result. similarly for undbolding goes to loop and then unbold finally. The same thing happens for italic and nonitalic text which has the same code like bold text code. Here is the code.

```
private void boldText2(){
       int typeface = Typeface.NORMAL;
       Spannable str = texto.getText();
       int selStart = texto.getSelectionStart();
       int selEnd = texto.getSelectionEnd();
       StyleSpan[] styleSpans = texto.getText().getSpans(selStart, selEnd, StyleSpan.class);

       for (StyleSpan styleSpan : styleSpans) {
               int oldStyle = styleSpan.getStyle();
               typeface = oldStyle;
               int spanStart = str.getSpanStart(styleSpan);
               int spanEnd = str.getSpanEnd(styleSpan);
               str.removeSpan(styleSpans);

               if (spanStart < selStart) {
                   str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(oldStyle), spanStart, selStart, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                  }

               if (spanEnd > selEnd) {
                   str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(oldStyle), selEnd, spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                 }

               if (oldStyle == Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC) {
                   str.removeSpan(styleSpan);
                   str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), spanStart, spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                 }
               if(oldStyle == Typeface.BOLD) {
                   str.removeSpan(styleSpan);
                }
       }

       if (typeface != Typeface.BOLD) {
           str = texto.getText();
           selStart = texto.getSelectionStart();
           selEnd = texto.getSelectionEnd();
           styleSpans = texto.getText().getSpans(selStart, selEnd, StyleSpan.class);

          if (styleSpans.length > 0) {
              int lastSpanEnd = 0;
              for (StyleSpan styleSpan : styleSpans) {
                  int oldStyle = styleSpan.getStyle();
                  int spanStart = str.getSpanStart(styleSpan);
                  int spanEnd = str.getSpanEnd(styleSpan);

  if (spanStart < texto.getSelectionStart()) {
                      str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(oldStyle), spanStart, selStart, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                      Log.d("TAG", "BOLD spanStart < texto.getSelectionStart()");
                    }

                  if (spanEnd > texto.getSelectionEnd()) {
                      str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(oldStyle), selEnd, spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    }

                  if (oldStyle == Typeface.ITALIC) {
                      str.removeSpan(styleSpan);
                      str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC), selStart, selEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                     }
              }

              if (selEnd != lastSpanEnd) {
                  str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), selStart, selEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                  }
          }

          else {
              str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), selStart, selEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
          }
      }
      }
```